# How to fix this blurred text in logo and convert its color to black in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, blur

Trying to sharpen this text to a normal state using Photoshop CS5 Extended. It is part of logo downloaded from internet. How to do it?
[image]

Comment: How big is the original image? how big do you need it to be after you edit it? What is a "normal state"? Can you [edit] your question to add more details?

Comment: The whole file is 13,0 KB and the size of it is 100/37 cm.

Comment: I mean size _in pixels_. Is this going to be used for print or web? This looks like a tiny image that you better off redoing than trying to save it, there's not a lot to save there.

Comment: That's right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You draw a rectangle (if that's needed) and write a new text object layered above the rectangle. Use what colors you need. Adjust letter spacing.

Unfortunately I cannot be sure what font is the original. Your image is so unsharp that numerous grotesque types seem to fit and even more will fit, if you stretch horizontally those which have too narrow letters.